# Rails: Make attributes readonly everywhere expect through specific service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I Have a rails model called `Product` which contains the attribute `price`.

Now I wan't to make sure, that no one (developers in my team) decides to change the price of a product by just doing e.g. `product.update_attributes(price: 2300)`, since prices should always be changed through a service called `ProductPriceManager`.

So instead you should do something like: `ProductPriceManager.update_price(product, 2300)`. The reason is, that a lot of other stuff should happen when a product changes, and this is what the `ProductPriceManager` takes care of.

What would be a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other possibilities to change the price other than with update attributes.

Would not be easier to add a callback in your Product class that calls to the `ProductPriceManager` if the product price changes?

Something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save ->(obj) { ProductPriceManager.price_changed(obj) }, if: ->(obj) { obj.price_changed? }
end
```

And what the `price_changed method` should do is just all the operations except changing the price (as it has just been updated)